# Xcode error. m:8794

Tags: ios, xcode

When running my code on one computer the app crashes with this error:

> *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2935.137/UIView.m:8794

But when running it on another computer the program works just fine.
What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Whitch Xcode / iOS version do you use ?

Comment: The assertion should have some explanation text associated with it.  What is says is vital to solving your problem.

Comment: See the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24549334/autolayout-crash-when-applying-transform-assertion-failure-in-layoutsublayers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was an iOS version issue. So when I tried building it on the Xcode simulator it worked. on the contrary of running it on an iPhone 4 / iOS 7..
Thank you  *David 'mArm' Ansermot* and *trojanfoe* for helping me solve it.