# iOS TableHeaderView auto resize with auto layout

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, autolayout

I want use TableHeaderView for dynamic content, the TableHeaderView auto resize itself depends on its content(many subviews or controls). But if I don't set

```
translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO
```

autolayout will print **"Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints"**. Because the TableHeaderView's height and width should depends on its content.

If I set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` the auto layout will be happy. But the app will crash with **"Assertion failure in -[UITableView layoutSublayersOfLayer:]"** on old iOS version.

So what should I do, anyone has othe solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24549334/autolayout-crash-when-applying-transform-assertion-failure-in-layoutsublayers

Comment: @SahebRoy maybe or may not, but it looks like no answers know what wrong with it, right? I still don't know how to resolve it.